# What is the term for when a general term is used to refer to something specific?

Tags: terminology, language-change

Is there a name for the linguistic phenomenon in which a general term gains a much more specific meaning?

For example, "Prohibition" is used to mean "Alcohol prohibition in the United States" or "Abolition" is used to mean "Abolition of slavery".

In Hebrew this is common for certain religious terms, e.g. *Eruv* meaning "mixture", but has expanded to mean [something else](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eruv). Same with *Seruv* meaning simply "refusal", but being used as refusal to grant a divorce.

Comment: _Specialization_ is one good term; it happens a lot. For instance, the Proto-Germanic root for 'dog' shows up in German as _Hund_, which just means 'dog', but in English it's specialized to _hound_, which is a special type of dog. Or German _Tier_ 'animal' shows up in English specialized as _deer_, to only one variety of animal. Quite a normal phenomenon; general terms are useful when you always have variable phenomena to refer to, but if it shows up too frequently in only one context, it'll get fixed there, like _seruv_ with giving a get.

Comment: Another term often used is *semantic narrowing*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A term commonly used to refer to this process of semantic change is [*semantic narrowing*](http://grammar.about.com/od/rs/g/semnarrterm.htm). This, along with other types of semantic change as well as the processes involved, are discussed on [WP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_change). As pointed out in a comment, this process is also sometimes known as *specialization*.

The opposite process is known as *semantic broadening/widening* or *generalization*.